# Assertion failed when OutputArray::create() run in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, opencv3.0

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void testThread(OutputArray image){
    image.create(100,32,CV_8U);
}
// void testThread(Mat image){
//     image.create(100,32,CV_8U);
// }
// void testThread(Mat& image){
//     image.create(100,32,CV_8U);
// }
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    Mat left= imread("./left.png",CV_8U);
    Mat right=imread("./right.png",CV_8U) ;

    thread t1(testThread,left);
    thread t2(testThread,right);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    // testThread(left);
    // testThread(right);

    return 0;
}
```

Why it performs normal in serial and throw exception in parallel? 
Also If you change the prototype of testThread into the second one it also performs normal in parllel but fail for the third one.
The exception information printed to the console is as follows:

```sh
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(_cols, _rows)) in create, file /home/linjiaqin/software/opencv-3.4.1/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp, line 1240
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(3.4.1) /home/linjiaqin/software/opencv-3.4.1/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp:1240: error: (-215) !fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(_cols, _rows) in function create
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to uncomment the "Mat right" , I just wanted to test only one thread.

Comment: I don't understand. So is it can only in serial?

Answer (score 0):

You have dangling reference.

Class `OutputArray` has a constructor which takes `Mat` by reference:

```
_OutputArray(Mat& m);
```

When you create thread you pass `left` - as `Mat` instance. Becuase a signature of thread body takes `OutputArray` which can take `Mat` this `Mat` as argument is created as copy. Then `OutputArray` takes this temporary object by reference. When `thread` started executing, `OutputArray` refers to destroyed temp `Mat` instance (`thread` needs to store only `OutputArray`, no temporary `Mat`).

Solution? Just pass original `left` into `OutputArray`:

```
thread t1(testThread, OutputArray(left));
t1.join();
```

in above code no temporary instance of `Mat` as copy of `left` is created.

Comment: Thanks, I have known that !

Comment: So why did you ask this question? I explained you where is your mistake. Dangling reference makes undefined behaviour.